# Asp.Net Web API get a list of enums as a get paramter does not serialize correclty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, asp.net-web-api

I have set my API foramter in the global.aspx as so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    Error = HandleSerializationErrors
};

settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = settings;
```

Here is my get action signature:

```
public List<WhatsNew> Get(int page, int start, int limit, [FromUri] IEnumerable<BusinessArchiveEnum> filterBy)
```

here is how the array of enums gets transmited:

[image]

here is the enum:

```
public enum BusinessArchiveEnum
{
    Undefined = 0,
    PurchaseOrder = 1,
    SalesOrder = 2,
    SentTaxInvoice = 3,
    ReceivedTaxInvoice = 4

}
```

when the action is invoked the filterBy parameter is set to Undefined!!! not like what I have sent..

Any idea why??

**UPDATE:**

I think I have solved it, the problem was in the client the enums should be passed with comma separator and not in a json array formation.

Comment: I can't be sure, but my guess is change `IEnumerable<BusinessArchiveEnum> filterBy` to `BusinessArchiveEnum[] filterBy`. I'm pretty sure that you need a more primitive type. But then again, it technically appears that it's already an array when viewing the JSON.

Comment: have tried to use primitive array type, did not help...